# How can I edit compressed JS files

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have had a developer create a website or app in React. This is already on a webserver and does what it should do. Now I want to develop the frontend myself, which would be no problem if I knew how to edit the code.

On the server I have an index.html, some stuff like favicon and a folder. This folder contains the folders "css", "js" & "media" and I don't understand their content. In the folder "css" are for example the files "main.12345.chunk.css" and "main.12345.chunk.css.map" Both look very cryptic.

Now I found out after some research that this is probably a compressed representation. Possibly compressed with Webpack?

But how can I edit these files in a meaningful way and understand what was coded there in the first place? Normally I would just download the file to be changed with Filezilla and edit it with an editor or Visual Studio code, but in this case I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those "cryptic" files are probably minified. Minification is a process where the original code is minified using several approaches, making it much smaller in size and also sometimes better performing. This is done by Webpack with a build process.

Those files are not meant to be develop with (or even read for that matter). Their sole purpose is to be optimized and be run in a production environment. It's very hard or even impossible to understand those, you would basically have to reverse-engineer them to understand what's going on. Many websites actually use minification for this additional bonus of protection of their application logic, because minimization basically obfuscates client side code. For example, the WhatsApp web client written in React is heavily obfuscated, in order to not allow anyone to write a WhatsApp client (there are [efforts for this particular example](https://github.com/sigalor/whatsapp-web-reveng), but it takes lots of time).

TL;DR: You have to get the original source files in order to edit them.

Comment: ...and then i replace the minified files with the original at the webserver?

Comment: @Dominic You edit the original files, fire up the webpack build step, which most likely will output a new folder like dist or build. The files in that folder are your new minified files you want to put on your webserver and replace the old ones with.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> But how can I edit these files in a meaningful way and understand what was coded there in the first place?

They **really** are not designed for editing.

Edit the original source code to the application, then run its build script and deploy the output from it.

Comment: The problem is, i don't have the original source code. But i can order them. So I develop based on the original source code and publish only the build versions on the server?